# Returning Result Based on 2 conditions from one Table

Tags: sql-server, query

Problem Statement: I have a table that holds three pieces of information (Number, Id, Type). Let’s call it table A:

```
╔══════╦════╦══════╗
║Number║ Id ║Type  ║
╠══════╬════╬══════╣
║ 1234 ║1111║Test 1║
║ 1234 ║2222║Test 1║
║ 1234 ║3333║Test 2║
║ 1234 ║4444║Test 2║
╚══════╩════╩══════╝
```

I have another table that holds 4 pieces of information (Number, Test1, Test2, ID). Let’s call it table B:

```
╔══════╦═════╦══════╦══════════════════╗
║Number║Test1║Test 2║ ID               ║
╠══════╬═════╬══════╬══════════════════╣
║ 1234 ║1111 ║      ║a1v1b0000006lmMAAQ║
║ 1234 ║2222 ║      ║a1v1b0000006lmNAAQ║
║ 1234 ║     ║3333  ║a1vf1000000qvTYAAY║
║ 1234 ║     ║4444  ║a1vf1000000qvTiAAI║
╚══════╩═════╩══════╩══════════════════╝
```

What I would like to do is, based on Number and Type from Table A, to search the Table B and return the corresponding ID.

The desired outcome is as follows:

```
╔══════╦════╦══════╦══════════════════╗
║Number║ ID ║Type  ║ ID               ║
╠══════╬════╬══════╬══════════════════╣
║ 1234 ║1111║Test 1║a1v1b0000006lmMAAQ║
║ 1234 ║2222║Test 1║a1v1b0000006lmNAAQ║
║ 1234 ║3333║Test 2║a1vf1000000qvTYAAY║
║ 1234 ║4444║Test 2║a1vf1000000qvTiAAI║
╚══════╩════╩══════╩══════════════════╝
```

NB: I have tried to use a decode but reading up on it, I am getting mixed signals whether this is the correct approach.

Comment: Thanks for replacing those screenshots - if you could add `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables, and `INSERT INTO` statements that populate the tables with your sample data, that would be very helpful to people who'd like to provide an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a quick solution that uses `union all`.

The first query finds the matching rows between `Table1` and `Table2` where `Table1.Type` = 'Test 1' and `Table1.Id` = `Table2.[Test 1]`

The second query finds the matching rows between `Table1` and `Table2` where `Table1.Type` = 'Test 2' and `Table1.Id` = `Table2.[Test 2]`

```
--demo setup
Declare @Table1 table (Number int, ID int, Type varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @Table1
  (Number, Id, Type)
VALUES
  (1234, 1111, 'Test 1'),
  (1234, 2222, 'Test 1'),
  (1234, 3333, 'Test 2'),
  (1234, 4444, 'Test 2');


Declare @Table2 table (Number int, [Test 1] varchar(10), [Test 2] varchar(10), ID varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @Table2
  (Number, [Test 1], [Test 2], ID)
VALUES
  (1234, '1111', '', 'a1v1b0000006lmMAAQ'),
  (1234, '2222', '', 'a1v1b0000006lmNAAQ'),
  (1234, '', '3333', 'a1vf1000000qvTYAAY'),
  (1234, '', '4444', 'a1vf1000000qvTiAAI');

--solution using union all
SELECT t1.Number
    ,t1.ID
    ,t1.Type
    ,t2.ID
FROM @Table1 t1
JOIN @Table2 t2
    ON t1.Type = 'Test 1'
        AND t2.[Test 1] = t1.ID

UNION ALL

SELECT t1.Number
    ,t1.ID
    ,t1.Type
    ,t2.ID
FROM @Table1 t1
JOIN @Table2 t2
    ON t1.Type = 'Test 2'
        AND t2.[Test 2] = t1.ID
```

---

```
| Number | ID   | Type   | ID                 |
|--------|------|--------|--------------------|
| 1234   | 1111 | Test 1 | a1v1b0000006lmMAAQ |
| 1234   | 2222 | Test 1 | a1v1b0000006lmNAAQ |
| 1234   | 3333 | Test 2 | a1vf1000000qvTYAAY |
| 1234   | 4444 | Test 2 | a1vf1000000qvTiAAI |
```

Answer (score 1):

This option joins the B table twice with a Case statement to place the ID value from either of the B table references into a single column.

Setup:

```
Create Table #A
(
 Number int, 
 ID int, 
 [Type] varchar(10)
)
INSERT INTO #A Values
(1234, 1111, 'Test 1'),
(1234, 2222, 'Test 1'),
(1234, 3333, 'Test 2'),
(1234, 4444, 'Test 2')
-----------------------------------------------
Create Table #B 
(
Number int, 
[Test 1] varchar(10), 
[Test 2] varchar(10), 
ID varchar(20)
)
INSERT INTO #B Values
(1234,1111,'','a1v1b0000006lmMAAQ'),
(1234,2222,'','a1v1b0000006lmNAAQ'),
(1234,'',3333,'a1vf1000000qvTYAAY'),
(1234,'',4444,'a1vf1000000qvTiAAI');
```

Query:

```
Select 
         a.*, 
         Case When b1.ID Is Null Then b2.Id Else b1.Id End As ID_val
From #A a Left Join 
     #B b1 On a.Number = b1.Number And a.Id = b1.[Test 1] Left Join  
     #B b2 On a.Number = b2.Number And a.Id = b2.[Test 2]

Drop Table #A
Drop Table #B
```

Result:

```
Number  ID      Type    ID_val
1234    1111    Test 1  a1v1b0000006lmMAAQ
1234    2222    Test 1  a1v1b0000006lmNAAQ
1234    3333    Test 2  a1vf1000000qvTYAAY
1234    4444    Test 2  a1vf1000000qvTiAAI
```

Answer (score 1):

You can unpivot table `B`'s `Test 1` and `Test 2` columns:

```
SELECT
  Number,
  TestID,
  Type,
  ID
FROM
  dbo.B
  UNPIVOT
  (
    TestID FOR Type IN ([Test 1], [Test 2])
  ) AS u
WHERE
  TestID <> ''
;
```

which will give you a dataset like this:

```
Number  TestID  Type    ID                
------  ------  ------  ------------------
1234    1111    Test 1  a1v1b0000006lmMAAQ
1234    2222    Test 1  a1v1b0000006lmNAAQ
1234    3333    Test 2  a1vf1000000qvTYAAY
1234    4444    Test 2  a1vf1000000qvTiAAI
```

You can see that the output has the same structure as `A` in terms of representation of the values of `Test 1` and `Test 2`, so just use the above query as a derived table or a CTE and join it to `A`:

```
WITH
  unpivotedB AS
  (
    SELECT
      Number,
      TestID,
      Type,
      ID
    FROM
      dbo.B
      UNPIVOT
      (
        TestID FOR Type IN ([Test 1], [Test 2])
      ) AS u
    WHERE
      TestID <> ''
  )
SELECT
  a.Number,
  a.ID,
  a.Type,
  b.ID
FROM
  dbo.A AS a
  INNER JOIN unpivotedB AS b ON a.Number = b.Number
    AND a.Type = b.Type
    AND a.ID = b.TestID
;
```

You can use [this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5ca44b1b33a089cac3599fbd130682ab&hide=15) at [image: dbfiddle logo]db<>fiddle.uk to play with this solution.